# Is there any way to "align left" the label for each field?

Tags: cognito-forms

I can't see a way but am very new to all this. Currently all the labels are centered and I need them to align to the left.

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

By default the labels for each field are left aligned they should show up just as they do in the build page when building your form. If you have embedding your form on your website, a CSS rule might be aligning the labels to the center rather then the left.

I understand you might not want to share your website via a public forum, if you would like help with the CSS rule that is effecting your from I would be happy to look at it via a [Bug Report](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/). I would then be happy to post the CSS correction here once we have identified the issue.